# REST Response - logging payload via readEntity(String.class) fails

Tags: java, rest, jersey, illegalstateexception

Consider this code for a REST proxy running under Jersey 2.22.2:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/foo")
public Response foo(String request) {

    logger.info("Request to /foo :\n" + request);

    WebTarget target = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(esbWsUrl).path("/foo");
    Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).post(Entity.entity(request, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));

    // problem is in the 2 lines below
    logger.info("Buffered: " + response.bufferEntity());
    logger.info("Response from /foo :\n" + response.readEntity(String.class));

    return response;
}
```

First I tried this without the `response.bufferedEntity()` and got `IllegalStateException` since `response.readEntity(String.class)` consumes from the underlying stream in the `Response`.

When I use `response.bufferEntity()`, I am able to call `response.readEntity(String.class)` multiple times (the buffering seems to work), yet the response returned by Jersey gives a zero bytes response.

```
$ curl -m 5 -i -X POST -d '{"input_values": "abc"}' http://localhost:9000/services/rest/foo
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 27 Oct 2016 08:18:09 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
X-Type: default
Server: nginx
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 364

curl: (28) Operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds with 0 out of 364 bytes received
```

Some relevent documentation is here: [Response.readEntity](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity-java.lang.Class-)

Can anyone please show me how to log the contents of the `Response`, before returning a valid `Response` ?

Maybe there is some stream handling issues I havent thought of, or perhaps another way to turn the `Response` entity to a string (without consuming the stream).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a completely new `Response`, based on the status code and entity of the previous one.